# Is it possible to write full python code inside Google Cloud Data Fusion?

Tags: python, csv, transform, pipeline, google-cloud-data-fusion

I'm building a pipeline which takes a CSV file and a table in BigQuery, and does some joining and transforming of the data to output a new table and a new CSV file (which are basically the same). The original issue (which is solved partly) was that the CSV file was outputting to Google Cloud Storage as several different partitions. I posted a question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70386422/how-to-output-write-to-a-single-csv-file-from-inside-google-cloud-data-fusion) about it.

Using the Repartitioner worked. However, as a temporary solution, we decided to write an external Python program (locally / on GitHub) to pull blobs from the Google Cloud Storage bucket, perform the appropriate combinations to combine the multiple CSV files into a single CSV file, and send that back into the bucket. This worked too.

Now what we are trying to do is figure out a way to integrate our Python solution (or a Python solution) into the Cloud Data Fusion pipeline itself. I found a Python Transform module in the Hub, and deployed that to our project. However, it only appears to allow for transforming Dictionaries and emitting those transformed dictionaries. Is this the only module / solution? Or is there a way to include more comprehensive Python code (full range of usability if possible) directly into the Data Fusion pipeline.

Thank you for any advice or suggestions!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Well, it turns out that it's not possible, because Data Fusion is intended to be a code-free environment. We discovered that Google Cloud Dataflow is useful for the same purposes (running pipelines) but these can be done manually by using Python and Apache Beam. So we switched to these tools. Thank you!